# Convert date format 01/05/2018 and 01/may/2018 to (dd/mm/yyyy) format and save same format into excel using c#

Tags: c#

I Have two type of date formats like 01/05/2018 and 01/may/2018. I want to convert both formats into (dd/MM/yyyy), how do I convert it and save into excel file. I have a problem in saving data into excel, the save not proper format, its change like a month comes first and sometimes date come first
the code is:-
mystring=mystring.tostring.parse("dd/MM/yyyy")

Comment: excel too have date format settings, have you consider looking into that too ?

Comment: Could you provide some code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes i have looks that but i don't get my answer

Comment: @BagishOjha lets get clear, you have successfully got dates string into proper format right? but all problem is in excel it is not in right format ?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and I tried the code below

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
string formattedDate = date.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy");
```

Comment: This doesn't compile...Can't really set a `String` in to a `DateTime` object

Comment: @JayV Edited as per your comments. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can provide *several* `formats` when using [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853(v=vs.110).aspx). So you can *parse* initial string into `DateTime` and then *format* the `DateTime` into required format.

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "01/05/2018",
    "01/may/2018",
  };

  string[] formats = new string[] {
    "d/M/yyyy",    // try this format first
    "d/MMMM/yyyy", // on fail try this one etc.
  };

  string[] results = tests
    .Select(item => DateTime.ParseExact(item, 
                                        formats,
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                        DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal))
    .Select(date => date.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy")) // '/' - to preserve / 
    .ToArray();

  Console.Write(Environment.NewLine, results);
```

Outcome:

```
01/05/2018
01/05/2018
```

Comment: i don't want to use parseexact method

Comment: @BagishOjha why not parse exact ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to do:

```
targetRange.NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

Where `targetRange` is either the `Cell` or `Column` that you want to have the required date format

The format must also be something that Excel understands and this is not always the same as what C# uses

Comment: where i can use this in excel or my assign string

Comment: You put this line wherever in your code that you set the values in the Excel spreadsheet. Usually you set the formats AFTER the value has been set to make sure that Excel doesn't change the formatting.
If you provide a working example, we can suggest more accurate potential solutions